# How to move code between similar versions targeting different environments?

Tags: version-control, language-agnostic

I'm developing a script that performs a certain core task, and using versions of that script in two different environments where some settings and steps along the way need to be different. What I am looking for is whether there exists an elegant way to handle the small differences between the two versions of the script. I'm sure developers face similar problems when developing software to be deployed on multiple platforms, but I don't have a specific name to pin on it.

What I do now is to open up the second script and manually replace the lines that need to be different. This is cumbersome, time-consuming, and a bit of a headache whenever I inevitably forget to comment out a line or change a string.

Example

```
[...]
path_to_something = "this/is/different"

use_something(path_to_something)

[...]

do_thing_A() # Only in environment A.

[...]

do_thing_B() # Only in environment B.

[...]
```

The omitted `[...]` parts are identical in both versions, and when I make a change to them, I have to either copy and paste each changed line, or if the changes are significant, copy the whole thing, and manually change the A and B parts.

Some ideas for possible solutions that I've come up with:

1. Write a script that automates the steps I manually take when moving the code back and forth. This exactly replicates the necessary steps, and it's quick and easy to add or remove steps as necessary.
2. Is this a use case for gitattributes?
3. Factor all the code that is identical between versions into separate files, so that the files containing the heterogenous code don't need to change at all, and thus don't need to be version-controlled, per se.
4. Some other tool or best practice that I don't know about to handle this type of workflow.

Looking around, I've found a question with a similar premise of maintaining different versions of code that does the same thing:

[Proper way to maintain a project that meets two versions of a platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882503/what-is-the-proper-way-to-maintain-a-project-that-meets-two-versions-of-a-platfo)

Solutions offered to that question:

1. Get rid of all the differences, then there is no problem to solve.  This may or may not be possible in my specific case, and certainly won't be possible in every case for everyone in the future. So maybe there is a more general solution.
2. Maintain two different branches of the code, even though they are nearly identical.  This is similar to what I do now, but I end up having to do a lot of copying and pasting back and forth between branches. Is that just inherent to software development?
3. Perform platform detection and wrap the differences in conditionals.  This adds a lot of ugly stuff in the code, but if I could successfully detect the environment and implement all the necessary differences conditionally, I would not have to make any changes to the code before sending it to the different environments.

**How do developers move code back and forth between similar, but different, parallel branches of a project?**

Comment: I'm afraid, but this topic must be closed as "too broad" + "offtopic" (or migrated to softwareengineering), but I'll start here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Language- and SCM-agnostic

1. Use one (two, three) **common class(es),** but **different interfaces** (interface per environment)
2. Move all env-specific from hardcode into external configuration, stored separately

### SCM-agnostic

Separate *tasks*, i.e.:

- Get clean common core
- Get changes on top core for every and each environment
- Move it into `$ENVS+1` branches in any SCM (`Core`+...+`EnvN`)

Changed workflow become

- Commit common changes to Core
- Merge Core to each Env-branch
- Test env-branches, fix env-specific changes if needed

---

## Private and personal, preferred for me and my habits

Variation of branch-tree solution

**Pure Mercurial-way, because I'm too lazy to maintain Env-specific branches**

Mercurial, one branch + MQ-queue with a set of patches (one mq-patch per Env, may be "set of queues /queue per Env/, one patch per queue")

Common code stored in immutable changesets, any changes, which convert plain core into environment-specific products, stored in patches and applied on demand (and edited when|if it needed).

- Small advantages over branch-way - single branch, no merges, more
  clean history
- Disadvantage - pure Mercurial, now trendy Git (git-boys
  are crying)